# Query XML on table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
 Content XML
)
```

I have inserted some values in `MyTable`:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES('<As>
          <A name="A_name_1">
            <Bs>
              <B name="B_name_1"></B>
            </Bs>
          </A>
          <A name="A_name_2">
            <Bs>
              <B name="B_name_1"></B>
              <B name="B_name_2"></B>
            </Bs>
          </A>
          <A name="A_name_3">
            <Bs>
              <B name="B_name_1"></B>
              <B name="B_name_2"></B>
              <B name="B_name_3"></B>
           </Bs>
         </A>
       </As>')
```

How can I use SQL Server to query `MyTable` to gain the result as follow?

I am a newbie on querying xml in RDBMSs. Please help me! Thank you so much!

```
   A                B
--------       -----------
A_name_1       B_name_1 
A_name_2       B_name_1 
A_name_2       B_name_2 
A_name_3       B_name_1 
A_name_3       B_name_2 
A_name_3       B_name_3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the XML method `nodes()` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)) thus:

```
SELECT  y.XmlCol.value('(@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS A_name,
        z.XmlCol.value('(@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS B_name
FROM    dbo.MyTable x
CROSS APPLY x.Content.nodes('As/A') y(XmlCol)
CROSS APPLY y.XmlCol.nodes('Bs/B') z(XmlCol)
```